# jQuery, getting individual results from a single class or tag

Tags: jquery

I need to get unique results from jquery to show different heights using the same class. Here is a sample I altered to show my issue on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V6Gx6/4/ one paragraph is clearly taller than the other but it gives the same results. I know that "this" can be used on .click or .hover events, but I'm not sure how to get it to work with this situation. Can you help me?

```
$(window).ready (function(){
    $("div").text($("span").outerHeight(true));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Gx6/8/)

```
$(window).ready (function(){
    $("span").each(function(){
        $(this).next('div').text($(this).outerHeight(true));
    })
});
```

This will go through each span and assign the div that is right next to it the text value of how high that span is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `id` attribute more:

http://jsfiddle.net/V6Gx6/7/

```
$(window).ready (function(){
    $("#uno").text($("#one").height());
    $("#dos").text($("#two").height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Gx6/10/)***

In fact those two paragraphs are different and you didn't quite manage to configure your selector properly to differentiate them. Using "div" will select every div so you are probably going to want to iterate that set and then use logic from that point to calculate the height of the correlating span.

Using `each` will allow you to iterate this set.

`$("div")` is going to produce a jquery object which holds an array of elements matching the selector "div", which is to say there will be an array of two div elements at this point.

The function `.each` is then going to take that array of elements and iterate them with a for loop. In the callback, there are optional parameters to send in. Note that the callback is the `function(){}` part. The optional parameters are going to be the index and the element, you can name the variables to your choosing (as in function(index,element)), and then you may use those inside of the anonymous function. When inside of the anonymous function, `this` will also refer to the current element in the array that is being worked on.

```
//Gather an array of elements matching <div> in a jQuery object
//Iterate through the array of elements using `each`
//Use an anonymous callback function
$("div").each(function(){
 //wrap the current element in a jQuery object to expose the API
 var t = $(this); 
 //set the text of the element to the size of the previous span's height
 //(previous relative to the current element) 
 t.text($(t).prev("span").outerHeight(true));
});
```